# development CI buidl practice

Tags: maven, continuous-integration

I am having a dispute will a colleague. We use maven to build our software and we both have a fair amount of experience with it. However something I have never seen done before is to disable maven tests by default with a profile. If the developer wants to skip tests then the -DskipTests option is available. His argument is that: You don't want every CI pipeline to re-run all the previous steps. Well if that is the case then instead of using:

```
mvn clean install
```

then use

```
- mvn clean 
- mvn compile test-compile
- mvn test
- mvn verify
- mvn package
```

However this also is unacceptable. He says at every company he has worked at this is standard. I cannot think of a single project I have looked at in OSS that uses maven that uses the convention of disabling mavens test functionality by default.

Am I confused? The whole selling point is that the build is standard and it requires direct intent to avoid running tests.

Comment: Whoever that sad has never understood Maven build life cycle that means a single step only use `mvn  clean verify`... and if you like to deploy artifacts to repository manager use `mvn clean deploy` instead...If you like to disable test as you mentioned use `-DskipTests` that's easy to handle without any profile etc. much easier..Tests are intended to check your code if it's working correct which means that should be done with each commit/push on a branch or main branch every time... integration tests / end to end test might be an options to be disabled...

Answer (score 3):

You don't skip tests as default.

And you don't let different CI steps repeat the ones before. So don't try to split the Maven build and first run `mvn test` and then `mvn verify` and then `mvn package` because you do a lot of work thrice.

Just use `mvn clean deploy` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Feels like I'm being gas lighted :-/